# Mobx State Tree not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I'm trying to make MST work with a simple model and a single component within my route.
The update function is called correctly but the component is not rendered again.

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import PDFMaker from '../store'


const PDFMakerForm = observer(({pdfmaker}) => {
  console.log(pdfmaker)

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <label>Project Name: </label>
        <input type="text"
               value={pdfmaker.name}
               onChange={(e)=>pdfmaker.setName(e.target.value)}/>
      </header>
    </div>

  )
})

const PDF = function () {
  return <PDFMakerForm pdfmaker={PDFMaker.create()} />
}

export default PDF
```

And the store file is as follows:

```
import { types } from "mobx-state-tree"

const PDFMaker = types
  .model({
    name: types.optional(types.string, ""),
    inputFile: types.optional(types.string, ""),
    outputDir:types.optional(types.string, ""),
    dataFile: types.optional(types.string, ""),
  })
  .actions(self => ({
    setName(newName) {
      self.name = newName
    }
  }))


export default PDFMaker
```

I'm not sure what the issue is as `PDFMakerForm` is wrapped in `observer` already, and a valid store is being passed to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `mobx-react` v8 and `mobx-react-lite` v4 [is bugged right now](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/3671) so you need to downgrade to the latest v7 or v3 respectively.

[image: Edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75864280]

I also recommend you to not create store like that, because if your component rerenders for some reason the store will be recreated too, you could keep it in the state or in the memo at least:

```
  const [pdfmaker] = useState(() => PDFMaker.create());
```

Comment: Found the real reason why it does not work right now, updated the answer